# Is it possible to create photo cleaner app using nativescript?

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I want to create iOS app which helps me to clean photo library.

Idea is simple - show all photos and videos from my iOS photo library with its sizes (regardless of where is media located - in iCloud or locally) with ability to preview them and to make selection for next deletion.

I have started to configure environment and figure out how to write apps with nativescript and can't google even how to get full list of photos/videos from iOS native Photos app.

Are there any limitations which will not let me to create an app described above in nativescript? Maybe it is not even possible to create in Xcode?

Comment: Is it possible to do in {N}? **Yes** it's  very much possible. But you may not get the code you could just copy paste, you will have to understand the way plugins work & code marshalling (Objective C to JS). The advantage of using {N} here would be cross platform UI, JavaScript as programming language for both iOS and Android, but you will have to use the native APIs to do the job.

Comment: Thank you! You can post your comment as answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to do in NativeScript? **Yes**.

It's very much possible. But you may not get the code you could just copy paste, you will have to understand the way [plugins](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/plugins) work & code marshalling ([Objective C to JS](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview)).

The advantage of using {N} here would be cross platform UI, JavaScript as programming language for both iOS and Android, but you will have to use the native APIs to do the job.